# Creating a div inside a table to add salary addition and deduction components

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a prototype for a Payroll management system using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

I have created a table and a dropdown button on its side. When I click the dropdown button. I want to display a div in the current active month.

Let that be December with active month number 12. There are 8 employees in the HTML table. In the div created using the dropdown button, I want to add basic salary, provident fund, bonus and other deductions, and display them in total. But the function I created doesn't work. I have created a division as a template and kept it as `display:"none"` in CSS. Please help me out.

I am getting error message as:

```
script1.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '8')
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous>
```

```js
var johnDoe = [1000, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
var johnDoe2 = [1000, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
var johnDoe3 = [1000, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
var activeMonth = 5;
//function for collapsible div

function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
  existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
}

const toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible-toggle');

const table_row = document.createElement('tr');
const div = document.createElement('div');
const table_data = document.createElement('td');

const salary_edit = document.getElementById('salary-change');
for (i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) {
  // console.log(toggle[i])
  //
  toggle[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(this.parentElement);
    const existingNode = this.toggle[i].parentElement.parentElement;
    console.log(existingNode);
    // console.log(existingNode);
    const currentTd = existingNode.childNodes[2 * activeMonth + 1];
    currentTd.classList.add('activeMonth');
    currentTd.appendChild(template[0]);

    console.log(currentTd.childNodes[1].classList.add('dropdownBox'));

    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < johnDoe.length; i++) {
      if (i < 3) {
        total += johnDoe[i];
      } else {
        total -= johnDoe[i];
      }
    }
    console.log(total);
    johnDoe[9] = total;
    const values = document.querySelectorAll('.values');
    console.log(values);

    values.forEach((v, i) => {
      v.textContent = johnDoe[i];
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible-div .collapsible-header button {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  background: var(--color-primary);
}

.collapsible-div .collapsible-body {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.salary-change {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-transactions">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sep</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--create a collapsible div-->
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <!--create a pay button-->
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay">Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>
          <button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay">Pay</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay ">Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay ">Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay ">Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay ">Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay " )>Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="collapsible-div">
            <span>John Doe</span>
            <span class="material-icons-sharp collapsible-toggle"
              >keyboard_arrow_down</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td><button class="pay-btn" id="btn-pay ">Pay</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="salary-change">
  <div class="monthEdit">
    <div>
      <button class="button" id="set ">Set</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="values">
    <div>
      <label for="basicSalary ">Basic Salary: </label>
      <input type="number " id="basicSalary " class="values" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="allowance ">Allowance: </label>
      <input type="number " id="allowance " class="values" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="bonus ">Bonus: </label>
      <input type="number " id="bonus " class="values" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="cit ">CIT: </label>
      <input type="number " id="cit " class="values" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="pf ">PF: </label>
      <input type="number " id="pf " class="values" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="tax ">TAX: </label>
      <input type="number " id="tax " class="values" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="total ">Total: </label>
      <input type="number " id="total " class="values" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was checking code and found a lot of code is missing like template div and CSS like `.dropdownBox{ ... }`. you mentioned you kept as display none but where it is in code?

Comment: @ækit i forgot to add it in here.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the application code I developed to toggle the "existing" data of items in a table using **jQuery**. If you have a different requirement, if you specify, I can update the application accordingly.

Below is a preview of the web page:

[image]

Below is the application source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-XJ3ntWHl40opEiE+6dGhfK9NAKOCELrpjiBRQKtu6uJf9Pli8XY+Hikp7rlFzY4ElLSFtzjx9GGgHql7PLSeog==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 15%;" scope="col">ID</th>
              <th style="width: 25%;" scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th style="width: 25%;" scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th style="width: 25%;" scope="col">Age</th>
              <th style="width: 20%;" scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="align-middle" scope="row"><div id="id1" style="display: none;">1234</div></th>
              <td class="align-middle"><div id="fn1" style="display: none;">John</div></td>
              <td class="align-middle"><div id="ln1" style="display: none;">Nash</div></td>
              <td class="align-middle"><div id="a1" style="display: none;">Engineer</div></td>
              <td>
                <button onclick="btn1EventHandler()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 7px;"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function btn1EventHandler(){
      $("#id1").toggle();
      $("#fn1").toggle();
      $("#ln1").toggle();
      $("#a1").toggle();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually i want to display a div inside a selected active table cell, whenever i press the show button or whatever button that is provided